# Center <td> and <th> elements in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter bootstrap 3. I have set the size of `th`. I want to center the text of each `th` `td`

Is there any bootstrap class for above?

http://jsfiddle.net/q5MCj/1/

Next thing i want is my textbox to be of exact size of the th. how can i do tht

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want the text "s.no" "item name" "quantity" to appear in the centre of th.

Comment: Use your own css like this http://jsfiddle.net/q5MCj/2/

Comment: `text-center` is a class in Bootstrap to center text.

Comment: @Pricey so, there isn't some class in bootsrap for this. can you help me in my second question. i.e i want the textbox to be of exact size of th.

Comment: @user2847429 in my example the textboxes are the same size as your `th` because of the use of `width: 100%; padding: 0;`.. at least in the browsers I have tested. You need to explain a bit more about what your trying to achieve, i.e. all `th` the same width or removing the borders on the textboxes? and there are some classes in bootstrap for doing this sort of thing but Bootstrap is a starter framework.. you are meant to have the freedom of adding your own CSS on top rather than applying a `text-center` class to every element in your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has a class called `.text-center` with the property `text-align:center` - use this to center the text within the `th`. [Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html)

As for making the `input` the same length as the `th`, you can simply set `width:100%` on `input`.

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JvC9v/) - pretty sure this is what you wanted.

Comment: Bootstrap 3 includes the `text-center` class to center text